# Limit the intermediate CA to be trusted only on one host

Tags: x.509

I'm exploring PKI and reached the following issue -
I'm generating root CA for an organization and intermediate CA per every user (unique).
But then it hit me that essentially any user (Alice) in the organization can "fake" a site for another user (Bob) in the following manner:

- the CA is trusted among all users.
- the site can send the entire chain (since the certs of his intermediate and the root are public)
- Bob's browser, once entering the site, see that the server cert is signed by the intermediate received from the server, signed by the trusted root ... and approves it.

**Is there any way to protect against such flows?**

I've read about different constraints but have yet to find one that can direct Bob's browser to require the intermediate CA to be stored in Bob's keychain.

I also deployed to root CA because MDM requires consent on any intermediate installation unless it "trusts it," - so it sounds like a chicken-egg issue.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly than you want all users to have their own trust anchor, which only they can use to create certificates but where the created certificates should also only be trusted by the users system itself and not others. The simplest way to achieve this is to let each user have their own root CA instead of their own intermediate CA derived from a common root CA. I'm not sure what  your current setup with common root and intermediates provides for you, what the simpler setup with one root CA per user does not.

Comment: OP, Normally, the site serves the certificate chain when the user first connects to the site, before the user has logged in.  If there is a unique 'intermediate CA per every user', then how does your site know which intermediate certificate to serve in the chain, before the user has even identified themselves?  I'm not sure I understand your setup.  Moreover, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this setup.  Are you trying to use intermediate certs as a way of granting/revoking access to your site on a per-user basis?  If so, using client certificates might be more feasible.

Comment: If you are creating an intermediate CA for each user, you have made each user a certificate signing authority. That is not how you should design a PKI infrastructure. The purpose of the intermediate certificates is to protect the root certificate and to sign certificates in place of the root. An intermediate can then be revoked. The intermediate must be protected in an almost similar manner to the root. By protected, I mean all of the private keys used for signing. The certificates are public.

Comment: I understand this is not conventional, but not all OS's (in this case macOS) allow to install intermediate CA.. therefore you only install root CA. But then you'd like that each user will its own ..... The use case is fairly simple MiTM for security purposes. The private key in such case has to reside in process memory .

Comment: All major operating systems including macOS support Intermediate certificates.

Comment: I'll correct this - allow you to install CA in the installation process without admin privileges. In most cases, you won't give users of the organization, admin privileges over their station.

Comment: If permissions do not permit intermediate installation, you cannot install a root either. That would make no sense if you could from a security viewpoint. Please do not use comments to chat. Update your post with all required information so that a fact based answer can be generated. You already know that you are not implementing PKI correctly. Once you do, post a question.